# What should be done to fix this answer?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Niall C.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/27/niall-c) discovered (and [gave notice](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39398/in-the-thing-are-victims-duplicated#comment-75040))that content was directly copied without attribution from IMDB to provide [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39398/in-the-thing-are-victims-duplicated#39400).

Unfortunately, I edited the answer to improve clarity and add paragraph breaks before the comment was posted.  [Kevin](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3267/kevin) then edited the answer to indicate that it was a quote from IMDB--but it was *no longer a quote* (because of my edit).

Should the text be returned to its original state (with Kevin's addition of attribution and link [with some additional text to explain "this film" refers to the 2011 version of *The Thing*]) so that it is actually a quote?

Since the answer was upvoted and *accepted*, deletion might be too harsh. (The answer addressed the stated question poorly, so acceptance is surprising. I would be tempted to be harsh because I was taken in by this post.)

Comment: Edit the IMDB entry to match?

Comment: @Kevin That would be a bit weird if people looked at edit history--the answer quotes a version at IMDB that written **later** (time travel is not supposed to be possible! :-). OTOH, most of the edit here would (I feel) improve the FAQ post at IMDB. I think I will wait for more community input before taking action.

Comment: Well, we are a scifi site. If anyone can edit posts through time, it's us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer has been unaccepted, after a more thorough reading I don't think it even addresses the question, and there is now a proper answer, so I have deleted the answer in question.

---

For the moment, I've pulled the part you changed significantly out of the quotation block. The only reason I didn't delete it outright was because it was upvoted and accepted, implying several people found it helpful, and the only other answer was a short one-liner. If there is a consensus that it's not an answer or the new answer has enough of the information, I'd be fine deleting it.